# Conversion of any format of date in mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert values into a table:

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,convert(datetime,'13-JUL-2019',101),1100,NULL,20);
```

But I receive the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''13-JUL-2019',101),1100,NULL,20)' at line 1.

Tried different syntaxes, however I couldn't solve this. 
Please some one help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `convert(datetime,'13-JUL-2019',101)` syntax is for MS SQL Server / Sybase.

Instead, use `STR_TO_DATE`.

Comment: Hey, I am using MySQL 8.0. As per the manual, there is no str_to_date() in 8.0 version. I am trying to execute the following query : INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('13-JUL-87'),1100,NULL,20); Output of to_date should be: 13-7-1987. But there is no to_date() in MySQL.

Comment: The function is str_to_date(). See documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date